# aws ec2 instance dns public name change

Tags: amazon-web-services

how to change this

```
http://ec2-3-135-20-94.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

to this

```
http://myname.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

I tried checking the vpc options but couldnt figure out where to go to change the auto-generated public dns

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a domain name of `myname.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` because the `amazonaws.com` domain belongs to Amazon.

However, you could **purchase your own domain** and use it to access your instance, such as: `www.hamdallah.com`

This would involve:

- Assigning a static Elastic IP address to the instance (so that the IP address does not change)
- Purchasing a domain name
- Creating an A-Record in the DNS system to point your desired domain name to the Elastic IP address

For details, see: [Routing traffic to an Amazon EC2 instance - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html)

Comment: Not sure if changing the A record is enough to delete the PTR record for the IP ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html)

> A public (external) DNS hostname takes the form ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com for the us-east-1 Region, and ec2-public-ipv4-address.region.compute.amazonaws.com for other Region.

As far as [DHCP options sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) concerned

`domain-name`:

> The domain name for your instances. You can specify a custom domain name (for example, example.com). This value is used to complete unqualified DNS hostnames. If you specify a custom domain name, you must set domain-name-servers to a custom DNS server

In both cases, you can't change the name you are trying to use.

If you really want to have a different DNS name for the ec2 instance, look into [route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/)